# How can I check a file at specific time + delay in java?

Tags: java, groovy, automation

I am using java + groovy and I have 2 files on a remote page. Those files contain statistics for 5 minutes and 30 minutes. For example, if I connect a device now at 11:42 he will show up in the 5 minutes report at 11:45 ( this is updated every 5 minutes + delay of 10 secs for writing the file) and in 30 minutes report he will show up at 12:15 ( this is updated every 30 minutes + delay of 2 minutes of writing the file).

How can I round the time to 5 minutes and some delay and to 30 minutes with some delay so I can read the file? I am adding device automaticaly and I have to wait for the device to apear in the reports so I can continue with other checks.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of need, I would use a scheduling framework (like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)) and configure your trigger in a [Cron way](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger). It is simple to put in place and will provide great maintainability gains in the future of your application.

For example **10 0/5 * * * ?** will fire every 5 minutes with a 'delay' of 10 seconds.

Comment: Instead of creating an Infinite loop. Its better to have Job scheduler such as quartz. Reason behind that is It has much more functionality which can be implemented easily. Like if you have to run two different things at different time. Scheduler will do it in more effective way and also consume less of your resources.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to calculate the next update, and then add a while loop:

```
while(true) {
    if (nextUpdate >= currentTime) {
        // Generate the report
        // nextUpdate = calculate next update time
    }
}
```

What code have you written?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)` This will provide 5 minutes after the current time, you can change it to 30 minutes accordingly.

Comment: but there is no rounding of the time. "if I connect a device now at 11:42 he will show up in the 5 minutes report at 11:45"

Comment: That isn't a question. You want it to appear at 11:47? What do you mean by Rounding? What are you rounding? Is it the current time? I think all that you need is in the `TimeUnit` class. Wish I could be more help.